# AWS EventBridge schedule to invoke API Gateway endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-event-bridge

I'm trying to build a schedule in AWS EventBridge that is going to invoke an API Gateway endpoint on a specific rate. However, I'm not able to specify the API Gateway endpoint when creating the schedule. I couldn't find examples in the documentation about the JSON body that I need to provide to specify the API Gateway ARN, endpoint and headers.

Follow AWS EventBridge documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-api-gateway-target.html

Comment: Why not the lambda behind the API gateway route?

Comment: I have multiple endpoints in the lambda mapped to different resources in the API Gateway and I need different events to trigger different endpoints.

Comment: @Carlos did you get anywhere with this? I'm having some trouble.

Comment: @ASimpleProgrammer what problem are you having?

Comment: You need to invoke the lambda directly.